# Show that $|x|\in H^1(-1,1)$.

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $$H^1(-1,1)=W^{1,2}(-1,1)=\left\{u\in L^2(-1,1)\mid \exists g\in L^2(-1,1): \forall \varphi\in \mathcal D(-1,1), \int u\varphi'=-\int g\varphi\right\}.$$

I just started Sobolev space, so how can I show that $|x|\in H^1(-1,1)$ ?

What I tried is to set $$g(x)=\begin{cases}-1&x\in (-1,0)\\ 0&x=0\\ 1&x\in (0,1)\end{cases}.$$
Then,
$$\int |x|\varphi'(x)dx=-\int_{-1}^0x\varphi'(x)dx+\int_0^1 x\varphi'(x)dx$$
$$\underset{IPP}{=}-\varphi(-1)+\int_{-1}^0 \varphi(x)dx+\varphi(1)-\int_0^1 \varphi(x)dx=\varphi(1)-\varphi(-1)+\int_{-1}^1 g(x)\varphi(x)dx.$$
Therefore, I'm very close of the solution, but I still have $\varphi(1)-\varphi(-1)$ that disturbes me.

Comment: $\varphi$ is a test function...

Comment: @user251257: And so ? Does it mean that $\varphi(1)=\varphi(-1)$ ? I don't have such a result.

Comment: test functions have compact support by definition.

Comment: I know this but why the support would be in $(-1,1)$ ? If it's like this, then $|x|\in H^1(\mathbb R)$, isn't it ? @user251257

Comment: neither $|x|$ nor its derivative is quadratic integral on the **whole** real line. You want to check $H^1(-1,1)$ only, so obviously the support of the test functions are in $(-1,1)$ only.